# Add «Load More» to data-output received with $.getJSON from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

While using Google Spreadsheets as a «Backend», I get the data of the spreadsheet via Googles JSON-Output (https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/MySpreadsheetID/1/public/values?alt=json) with jQuerys $.getJSON(…), process the data (add the values to arrays) and add the data/content to the frontend with a loop through the arrays.

Now let's say the Google Spreadsheet has about 200 Rows and about 10 Columns (a lot of data) filled with data. I'm creating Info-Cards on the frontend with this data (each row = one card, 200 rows = 200 cards…). This obviously quite some work for the browser on «first load».

**How can I add a «Load More»-Routine, to lower the browser-load/-work while building the frontend?**

The goal is to load the full JSON, but only add the data of X rows (= X cards) to the frontend first, and load the next X rows only if the user clicks on a «Load More» element, then load the next X rows on the second click and so on till all rows/cards have been build.

My *simplified* Code (get all the rows & create all the cards at first load):

```
var rowCount,
    row1 = [],
    row2 = [],
    row3 = [],
        $cardsContainer = $('.js-cardsContainer');

function processDataGoogle(data) {
    rowCount = Object.keys(data.feed.entry).length;

    for(var i in data.feed.entry) {
        row1.push("" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$row1.$t);
        row2.push("" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$row2.$t);
        row3.push("" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$row3.$t);
    }

}

function addCards() {
    for(var index = 0; index < rowCount; index++) {
        $cardsContainer.append($('<article class="card"><h1>'+row1[index]+'</h1><p>'+row2[index]+'</p><a href="#">'+row3[index]+'</a></article>'));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/MySpreadsheetID/1/public/values?alt=json', function(data) {
        processDataGoogle(data);
        addCards();
    });

});
```

Comment: We can change `addCards()`, and add **Load More** logic there.

Comment: Something like this : http://plnkr.co/edit/94wmhzRQd1qdzMpRr9xr?p=preview. (Note : I had to use dummy data instead of Google Spreadsheet data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change `addCards()`, to load only items once `Load More` is clicked :

```
var loadMoreClicks = 1;

function addCards() {

var CARDS_TO_LOAD = 10; // number of cards to load once load more is clicked.
    for(var index = (CARDS_TO_LOAD * (loadMoreClicks - 1 )); index < (CARDS_TO_LOAD * loadMoreClicks); index++) {
        $('.js-cardsContainer').append($('<article class="card"><h1>'+row1[index]+'</h1><p>'+row2[index]+'</p><a href="#">'+row3[index]+'</a></article>'));
    }
}

$("#load-more").click(function(){
        loadMoreClicks += 1;
        addCards();    
});
```

In HTML :

```
<button id="load-more">Load More</button>
```

**Note:** Handling needed once all items have been loaded.

Comment: That looks fantastic, thx Ankit! But how can i stop the for-loop when `index` (-1) arrives at `rowCount`? (lets say there are 194 rows, CARDS_TO_LOAD is 10, with the 19th click i get the last 4 rows, but it actually tries 10 times — so it may fire an error cause theres no index[194])

Comment: @albuvee, I have updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/94wmhzRQd1qdzMpRr9xr?p=preview) with logic for handling such cases. It might help.